# Handling children taps

Tags: flutter

I'm beginner on Flutter and I'm trying to create a custom Widget called IconSelect. It should render a list of icons with a legend and the user will choose only one option. When the user taps an icon, it should change the background color of the selected icon and deselect all others.

My first aproach was to create an IconSelect class as a Stateful widget, and another widget called IconSelectItem as Stateless. And the IconSelect would have a children property, containing instances of IconSelectItem.

How can I handle the children taps to change the IconSelect state? Any ideas of others aproaches?

My code:

```
class IconSelect extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<IconSelectItem> children;
  final ValueChanged<int> onSaved;

  IconSelect({
    this.children,
    this.onSaved
  });

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new IconSelectState();
}

class IconSelectState extends State<IconSelect> {
  int _selectedValue;

  _handleTap(int value) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedValue = value;
    });

    widget.onSaved(_selectedValue);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Row(
      children: widget.children,
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // I tried the code below without success
    widget.children.forEach((IconSelectItem item) {
      item.onTap = _handleTap(item);
    });
  }
}

class IconSelectItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final Icon icon;
  final String legend;
  final int value;
  VoidCallback onTap;
  final bool _selected = false;

  IconSelectItem({
    Key key,
    this.icon,
    this.legend,
    this.value,
  }) : super(key: key);

  _handleTap() {
    onTap();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => _handleTap(),
      child: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new CircleAvatar(
            radius: 30.0,
            child: icon,
            backgroundColor: _selected ? Colors.blue : Colors.white,
          ),
          new Center(
            child: new Text(legend),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You need call setState on IconSelectItem's ancestor.

Comment: @najeira can u show me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

call `setState` on IconSelectItem's ancestor:

```
class YourPageState extends State<YourPage> {
  int _selectedValue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Row(
      children: widget.items.map((Item item) {
        return new GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            // this class is a ancestor of IconSelectItem.
            // setState will rebuild children.
            setState(() {
              _selectedValue = value;
            });
          },
          child: new IconSelectItem(
            icon: item.icon,
            legend: item.legend,
            value: item.value,
            // every time _selectedValue changes,
            // IconSelectItem is rebuild by setState.
            selected: item.value == _selectedValue,
          ),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}

class IconSelectItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final Icon icon;
  final String legend;
  final int value;
  final bool selected;

  IconSelectItem({
    Key key,
    this.icon,
    this.legend,
    this.value,
    this.selected = false,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        new CircleAvatar(
          radius: 30.0,
          child: icon,
          backgroundColor: selected ? Colors.blue : Colors.white,
        ),
        new Center(
          child: new Text(legend),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```